# How to count how many cells say "TRUE" in one column while having a specific name in one of two other columns

Tags: excel, vlookup, lookup, countif

I'm trying to figure out a formula in Excel that finds if "New England Patriots" is in either column E (Home Team Name) or column H (Away Team Name), and also has the value "TRUE" in column S. What is the best way to go about doing this?

I've tried COUNTIF, COUNTIFS, and VLOOKUP and must be doing it wrong.

=COUNTIFS(scores!E:E, C2, [scores!H:H, "TRUE"])

Doing this gives me the error message about not using conflicting workbooks. Is there a workaround? For reference, C2 in the formula is the team name I want it to search for.

Answer (score 1):

For this answer, I'm going to assume your table looks like this (I realize your columns are different), and the output you want is a count of the number of rows meeting that criteria:

```
A          B          C
Giants     Patriots   TRUE
Patriots   49ers      TRUE
Giants     49ers      FALSE
Steelers   Jets       TRUE
Jets       Patriots   FALSE
Steelers   Patriots   TRUE
```

Since you can't do an "or" with `COUNTIFS` criteria, just combine two different executions of that function:

`=COUNTIFS(A:A, "Patriots", C:C, TRUE) + COUNTIFS(B:B, "Patriots", C:C, TRUE)`

...in this case, returning 3.

However, if its possible that "Patriots" can appear in both columns A and B at the same time, you need to be more careful to subtract out the lines that appear in both sets, otherwise they will be double counted.

`=COUNTIFS(A:A, "Patriots", C:C, TRUE) + COUNTIFS(B:B, "Patriots", C:C, TRUE) - COUNTIFS(A:A, "Patriots", B:B, "Patriots", C:C, TRUE)`

Obviously you can reference a cell instead of hard coding a string too, for example if 'Patriots' is in `F7`:

`=COUNTIFS(A:A,F7,C:C, TRUE) + COUNTIFS(B:B,F7,C:C, TRUE) - COUNTIFS(A:A, F7,B:B, F7,C:C, TRUE)`

Comment: Thank you so much, this worked! Although it didn't work in my original xlsx spreadsheet because the TRUE and FALSE values are products of a formula in that column, but saving it as a .csv removed the formulas and left the outputs (TRUE and FALSE) and let me use that formula. Is there any way to keep it as an xlsx while still searching the column for TRUE or FALSE?

Comment: You'll have to say more about what the formula is doing (please edit your original question).  I put in a simple formula into column C using boolean `AND` with 2 other cells as source data, and it appears to still work.